# Ao criar um Usuário novo, o usuário que está sendo usado é deslogado e o usuário novo é Logado automaicamente

Tags: laravel, controller

Eu estou tendo um problema com o método de criar um novo usuário no laravel, pois eu alterei o método de registrar usuários no meu sistema para apenas usuários administradores poderem criar novos usuários, porém todas as vezes que eu crio um usuário novo, o meu usuário atual é deslogado e o site loga no novo usuário.

meu arquivo **create_users.blade.php**

```
 @extends('layouts.menu')


@section('content')

<?php
$status = (bool) rand(0, 1) ? "checked" : null;
?>

<br><br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-10 ">
        <div class="pull">
            <h2>Criar Novo Usuário:</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" class="col-10">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Nome:</strong>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                            name="name" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
                        @error('name')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Email:</strong>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                            name="email" required autocomplete="email">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Senha:</strong>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <input id="password" type="password"
                            class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required
                            autocomplete="new-password">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>CPF:</strong>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <input id="CPF" type="text" class="form-control @error('CPF') is-invalid @enderror" name="CPF"
                            required autocomplete="new-CPF" minlength="11" maxlength='11'>
                        @error('CPF')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Setor:</strong>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="setor" id="setores">
                            <option selected>Selecione o Setor</option>
                            @foreach ($setor as $s)
                            <option value="{{ $s->id }}">{{ $s->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Cargo:</strong>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="cargo" id="cargos">
                            <option selected>Selecione o Cargo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Função (Para Permissões):</strong>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="roles" id="roles">
                            <option selected>Selecione a Função</option>
                            @foreach ($role as $ro)
                            <option value="{{ $ro->id }}">{{ $ro->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="status" value="1" id="switch1"
                    <?php echo $status; ?> >
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="switch1">Ativo</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-1 text-center" style="padding-top: 25px;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>
</div>

<script src="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#setores').on('change', function(e) {
        var setor_id = e.target.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('cargos') }}",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                setor_id: setor_id
            },

            success: function(data) {
                $('#cargos').empty();
                $.each(data.cargos, function(index, cargos) {
                    $('#cargos').append('<option value="' + cargos.id +
                        '">' + cargos.name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

@endsection

---

Meu **RegisterController**

```
   class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

public function index()
{

}

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string','min:5', 'max:25'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'max:20'],
        'CPF' => ['required', 'unique:users','integer'],
        'setor' => ['required','integer'],
        'cargo' => ['required','integer'],
        'status' => ['boolean'],
    ]);
}
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' =>       $data['name'],
        'email' =>      $data['email'],
        'password' =>   Hash::make($data['password']),
        'CPF' =>        $data['CPF'],
        'setor_id' =>   $data['setor'],
        'cargo_id' =>   $data['cargo'],
        'status' =>     $data['status'],
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('usuarios/create')->with('message', 'Usuário criado com Sucesso!');
}

public function edit($id)
{
// $user = User::findOrFail($id);
// return view('users.edit',compact('user'));
}
```

}

---

**EDIT** 
Eu havia colocado o Controller errado.

---

Meu **RouteServiceProvider.php:** (Esse arquivo não foi alterado.)

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

/**
 * The path to the "home" route for your application.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public const HOME = 'home';

/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //

    parent::boot();
}

/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    //
}

/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}

/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

}

---

e minhas Rotas do **web.php**

```
Route::get('usuarios/create', 'User\UserController@index');
Route::get('/cargo', 'User\UserController@selectBoxAjax_users')->name('cargos');
Route::get('senha/update', 'User\UserSettingsController@edit');
```

---

Meu Model **User**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```

{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles;

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */

public function index($user_id){
   $user_id -> Auth::user()->id;
}

public $timestamps = false;

protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'password','CPF','setor_id','cargo_id','email',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

}

---

Será que alguém consegue me ajudar? eu procurei em muitos lugares, olhei praticamente toda a documentação do laravel e não to conseguindo encontrar nada sobre. Se alguém conseguir me ajudar eu ficarei muito agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, eu dei mais uma analisada no meu **RegisterController** e acabei percebendo uma linha que havia passado despercebida por mim antes.

```
use RegistersUsers;
```

Ao abrir esse arquivo, vi que estava ali meu problema

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
                ? new Response('', 201)
                : redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Como eu havia usado o Controller padrão criado pelo `php artisan ui vue --auth` e não tinha prestado atenção neste arquivo antes, não tinha percebido a linha `$this->guard()->login($user);` que era o que fazia com que o usuário fosse logado ao criar.
Agradeço aos que tentaram me ajudar, o problema mesmo foi falta de atenção.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria você postar mais sobre o `User`, como `Middleware`, o próprio `Model`, entre outras coisas que interagem com o User e que podem estar afetando.

Para uma solução paliativa sugiro utilizar a função `login` do `Auth`no fim do `store`. Dessa forma, o usuário logado será o usuárioque você passar para função.

```
$user = User::where('id',$idUsuarioAtual)->first();
Auth::login($user);
```

`$idUsuárioAtual` pode vir como parâmetro ou algo assim.
Lembrando que essa é uma solução paliativa e está longe do ideal. Edita a pergunta fornecendo mais informações para ser mais fácil dizer aonde está o problema!

Comment: Eu dei mais uma analisada no meu Controller novamente e encontrei o causador do meu "problema", to postando uma resposta com o que fiz pra resolver, porém obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Esta resposta deveria ser um comentário, porém ainda não tenho pontos para tal.

Você poderia compartilhar o que você tem dentro do método index do controller? Também o que tem na lógica do assignCargo no seu model.

Fora estes dois pontos não vejo nada que possa estar causando este comportamento no seu código.

Comment: o meu controller está sem função index ainda, porém descobri o que estava fazendo o código reagir dessa maneira. Vou postar uma resposta com a resolução, porém obrigado pela ajuda.